# Logic Gate - What will be the input?

Tags: logic-gates

i = 0 & s = 1

[image: img]

An input of 3rd NAND is 1, 4th NAND input is 0...
What will be the second input of 3rd and 4th NAND gate? Why?

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is known as a gated D-latch. When s=0, a and b are 1, regardless of the value of i, so the output o remains constant. In particular, if o=1, then c=0, and if $o=0$, then c=1.

When s=1, then a = NOT i and b = i. So if i=0, then a=1 and b=0 and hence c=1, which means o = 0. If i=1, then a=0 so o=0, and therefore c=1.

(Notice that c = NOT o at all times.)

Answer (score 0):

Gate 4 has a zero (b) as one of the inputs, so it outputs a one (c) regardless of the other input. Hence gate 3 will get a one and a one, and its output (o) should be zero.

Comment: Gate 4 has input 0 and 0 ?

Comment: Because b is 0 (one input of gate 4), c must be high. Since c is high and a is high, o is 0, and therefore both inputs of gate 4 are low.